# Android Display Camera Interface

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to make an app that will be used to take a picture, so I created an Android Studio Project with a blank activity and tried placing code from Android's Developer page in MainActivity.java,
but no matter where I placed the code, I couldn't get it to cause the app that runs to display a camera interface.

```java
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }
    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to android development...

Comment: You need to give permission for using camera .

Comment: @MohammadArman I added the following two lines to the manifest, 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
is there more to do?

Comment: Is permission asked , after adding  ? You need to do runtime also.

Comment: Permission is not asked? How do I add the permission at Runtime?

Comment: if my answer worked ,please mark as answer . if you think I really put some effort into it , thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a camera , you need to ask user for permission first . In developers page its clearly mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera#java) . Sample code will be like this

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
Camera mCamera;
CameraPreview mPreview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    Button btnCamera = findViewById(R.id.camera);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((this)
                , Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((this),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }

    }
    btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mCamera  = getCameraInstance();
            // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(getApplicationContext(), mCamera);
            preview.addView(mPreview);
        }
    });

}
public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c;
}}
```

Here is layout sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Camera"
    android:id="@+id/camera"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```